# Prove that $[\sum_{k = 1}^\infty|\langle f,\phi_k\rangle|^2]^{1/2}\geq[\sum_{k = 1}^\infty|\langle g,\phi_k\rangle|^2]^{1/2} - \varepsilon$

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm working through some solutions as part of preparation for an exam in functional analysis, and my lecturer has made the following claim

> Since $||f - g||_2<\varepsilon$, we have, by the triangle inequality, that
> \begin{equation}
> \left[\sum_{k = 1}^\infty|\langle f, \varphi_k\rangle|^2\right]^{1/2}\geq\left[\sum_{k = 1}^\infty|\langle g,\varphi_k\rangle|^2\right]^{1/2} - \varepsilon\tag{1}\label{1}
> \end{equation}

For context, $M = \lbrace \varphi_k\in L_2(a, b):k\in\mathbb{N}\rbrace$ here, is an orthonormal sequence, and we are attempting to prove that, if
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^\infty\left|\int_a^x\varphi_k(t)~dt\right|^2 = x - a
$$
then $M$ is total in $L_2(a, b)$. The claim alluded to above is simply a single step in the proof of the aforementioned claim, and I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how the application of the triangle inequality leads to \eqref{1}.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you could adapt $\|f-g\| \ge \|g\|-\|f\|$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\varphi_k$ is an orthonormal system then by Bessel inequality we have
$$ \left (\sum_{k=1}^\infty |\langle h,\varphi_k\rangle |^2\right )^{1/2}\le \|h\|_2$$
Taking $h=f-g$ we get
$$ \left (\sum_{k=1}^\infty |\langle f,\varphi_k\rangle -\langle g,\varphi_k\rangle|^2\right )^{1/2}\le \|f-g\|_2$$
Denote $a_n=\langle f,\varphi_k\rangle,$  $b_n=\langle g,\varphi_k\rangle $
and $c_n=\langle f,\varphi_k\rangle -\langle g,\varphi_k\rangle .$ The left hand side can be interpreted as the norm in $\ell^2$ space of the sequence $\{a_n-b_n\}_{n=1}^\infty,$ i.e. as $\|a-b\|_{\ell^2}.$ By triangle inequality we get $\|a-b\|_{\ell^2}\ge \|b\|_{\ell^2}-\|a\|_{\ell^2}.$ Hence
$$\left (\sum_{k=1}^\infty |\langle f,\varphi_k\rangle|^2\right )^{1/2}=\|a\|_{\ell^2}\ge  \|b\|_{\ell^2}-\|a-b\|_{\ell^2}\ge \left (\sum_{k=1}^\infty |\langle g,\varphi_k\rangle|^2\right )^{1/2}-\|f-g\|_2$$
**Remark** If $\varphi_k$ is an orthonormal basis then we have equalities in the first two formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f' = \sum_k \langle f, \phi_k \rangle \phi_k $, and similarly for $g'$.
Note that $\|f'\|^2 = \sum_k |\langle f, \phi_k \rangle|^2 $ and also note that $\|f'-g'\| \le \|f-g \| < \epsilon$. Hence the triangle inequality gives $\epsilon > \|g'\| - \|f'\|$, which is the desired result.